# Design a class that could only be instantiated by a specific class(by make_unique if possible)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am implementing a naive memory pool, and there are two classes in my implementation.

The `FixedMemoryPool<T>` and `MemoryBlock<T>`

The `FixedMemoryPool` provides interfaces to users like `newElement`, and it manage memory through `MemoryBlock`.

And it's clear that none of the user should have accessibility to `MemoryBlock`, it's lifecycle is completely managed by FixedMemoryPool. For each `MemoryBlock<T>`, it can only be created by `FixedMemoryPool<T>`.

Here's my implementation.

```
template
<typename T>
class FixedMemoryPool;

template<typename T>
class MemoryBlock
{
    friend class FixedMemoryPool<T>;
    using blockPtr = unique_ptr<MemoryBlock<T>>;
    struct _ConstructorTag { explicit _ConstructorTag() = default; };
public:
    MemoryBlock(size_t blockSize, _ConstructorTag)
        :data(reinterpret_cast<T*>(operator new(sizeof(T) * blockSize))), allocatedCounter(0), next(nullptr)
    {
    }

    ~MemoryBlock()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i != allocatedCounter; i++) {
            (data + i) -> ~T();
        }
        operator delete(data);
    }
private:
    T* data;
    size_t allocatedCounter;

    blockPtr next;

    template
    <typename... Args>
    T* construct(Args&&... args)
    {
        return new (data + (allocatedCounter++)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock&) = delete;
    MemoryBlock& operator=(const MemoryBlock&) = delete;
};

template
<typename T>
class FixedMemoryPool 
{
public:
    using valueType = T;

    FixedMemoryPool(size_t blockSize = 64)
        :blockSize(blockSize), head(make_unique<MemoryBlock<T>>(blockSize, MemoryBlock<T>::_ConstructorTag{}))
    {
    }

    FixedMemoryPool(const FixedMemoryPool&) = delete;
    FixedMemoryPool& operator=(const FixedMemoryPool&) = delete;

    FixedMemoryPool(FixedMemoryPool&& pool) = delete;
    FixedMemoryPool& operator=(FixedMemoryPool&&) = delete;

    template
    <typename... Args>
    T* newElement(Args&&... args)
    {
        //...
    }

    ~FixedMemoryPool() = default;
private:
    void expand()
    {
        // ...
    }

    size_t blockSize;

    unique_ptr<MemoryBlock<T>> head;
};
```

Thanks for this [link](http://seanmiddleditch.com/enabling-make_unique-with-private-constructors/). I know how to enabling make_unique with private ctor.
However, i want to know if there is any better way to fulfill my desire.

Also, is my usage to `operator new` and `operator delete` right?

Comment: For improvements in already working code, you should post in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and *not here*.

Comment: Make it a private class inside your pool?

Comment: @gsamaras Sorry, but i am not determined that whether this code could work or not. Especially the part that relative to memory management

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher You mean move the whole ```MemoryBlock``` into the declaration field of ```FixedMemoryPool```?

Comment: Yes. Seems like the MemoryBlock itself only lives for the Pool.

Answer (score 1):

A bit off-topic, but there is no reason for `MemoryBlock` to be aware of type `T`.

In your implementation, when you create a `MemoryBlock` and then destroy it, it ends up invoking destructors of objects that were never constructed, which is undefined behaviour.

`MemoryBlock` should only be aware of object size and and number of objects in a block.

Comment: This so-called "memory pool" is actually a component of my compiler lesson's work. Since in the RE to NFA phase, will generate many small state/edge object. And i miss the code of ```construct``` in the first version of question. I use a counter to point to the allocated objects, in the destruction phase. I've just call the destructor one by one, will it invoking destructors of object that were never constructed? I am really confusing about ```operator delete``` yet.